# Firebase Login troubleshoot

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Having trouble creating a login account. Every time I try and create an account my error handling will return Failed to create an account and it displays the user as null.

Signup.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, Form, Button, Alert } from "react-bootstrap"
import { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"

const Signup = () => {
    const emailRef = useRef()
    const passwordRef = useRef()
    const passwordConfirmRef = useRef()
  const { signup, currentUser } = useAuth()
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)



  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Passwords don't match")
    }

    try {
      setError("")
      //this is so that the user can't click the button multiple times and also so that there isnt a error loading 
      setLoading(true)
      await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
    } catch { 
      setError("Failed to create an account")
    }
    setLoading(false)
}


   return (
     <>
       <Card>
         <Card.Body>
           <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign Up</h2>
            {currentUser && currentUser.email}
           {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
           <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
             <Form.Group id="email">
               <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
               <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
             </Form.Group>
             <Form.Group id="password">
               <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
               <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
             </Form.Group>
             <Form.Group id="confirm-password">
               <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
               <Form.Control
                 type="password"
                 ref={passwordConfirmRef}
                 required
               />
             </Form.Group>
             <Button disabled={loading }type="submit" className="w-100">
               Signup
             </Button>
           </Form>
         </Card.Body>
       </Card>

       <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
         already have an account? Login
       </div>
     </>
   );

  }
```

AuthContext.js

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { auth } from '../FireConfig'



const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}


export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) 

    function signup(email, password) { 
        auth.createuserwithemailandpassword(email, password)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setCurrentUser(user);
      });
      return () => unsubscribe(); // Unsubscribe from the onAuthStateChanged listener on cleanup
    }, []);


    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup
    };



    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

FireConfig.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth"; 

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
});

export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

I went back in the video I was following I think it may just be old syntax but not entirely sure. this is the link to the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKwu15ldZ7k&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

Comment: I assume you enabled Email as a signup method. Could you paste the concret error response in text form from the browser's network console (F12) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AuthProvider component, you have written `createuserwithemailandpassword` instead of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

```js
function signup(email, password) { 
  return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch((error) => {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    });
}
```